# Why did I get this random pop-up?

Tags: 20.04, authentication, gvfs

So I woke up today and I am greeted with this.

```
          Authentication Required
Authentication is required to run gvfsd-amin daemon

                 Password
Cancel                                 Authenticate
```

I don't know what  gvfsd-admin does or why it's daemon asks for authentication, and I have never done anything with this in the past. I have seen instructions on how to get rid of it, but what I want to know is why it popped up in the first place without my prompt. I have only been using Ubuntu for a month, so I am quite new.